# Uploaded file has 0 file size

Tags: alfresco

I am using Alfresco Enterprise Version 3.3.3 and Alfresco WebServices API for Java.

When uploading a file more than 10MB, it will appear in the Alfresco with size 0. There is no any exception messages from console. Why is this occuring?

Comment: Why are you using such an old version of Alfresco?

Comment: Try uploading with the explorer UI, mostly that one will give better errors on that old version. so instead <host>/share use <host>/alfresco . And check the logs in <tomcat>/logs directory.

Comment: Could you post your code? If you have to use WebServices, nothing much can be done without looking at your code.

Comment: @gragravarr there are always reasons for not being able to upgrade, I'm stuck at 3.4.0 for the time being...

Comment: We've still got a customer who is on 2.2.8 ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Throwable interface instead of Exception class in catch block.
then you can get proper exception.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem in my project and I figured out the problem.

The REASON behind this is we actually create file in two operations.
First We create the content node in alfresco and add basic properties.
Second We get the content writer of newly created content and try to write the data from our source file.
It appears that if we have file with size more then 10 Mb it throws the exception during second operation.

Now once exception is thrown data is not written but the node is already created in alfresco and it remains as it is.